# What is the meaning for the unit kilogram-mole?

Tags: units, physical-chemistry, si-units, absolute-units

Recently, I came across the unit J/(kg-mole * K). What is the meaning of kg-mole? Please explain me the meaning behind it.

Thanks in advance,

Rram

Comment: Can you quote the place where you found this unit, with some context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **mole** is defined as the number of atoms in 12 g of ${}^{12}\mathrm{C}$.

Some people also call this the **gram-mole** (g-mole), i.e. 1 mole = 1 g-mole. The **kg-mole** is then defined bt 1 kg-mole = 1000 g-mole = 1000 mole, so it is the number of atoms in 12 kg of ${}^{12}\mathrm{C}$.

If you really want to confuse people you could also use **lb-mole**...

Comment: In the world of chemical engineers in industry, they are only interested in getting the chemical ratios of mixtures correct, so U.S. engineers typically do use the lb-mole.

Comment: U.S. units confuse everybody, including some U.S. engineers.